# having trouble using operands between a range and list

Tags: python

Any idea why i get this message for the below code? "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'int'"

```
# Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds

suits = ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D']
card_val = (range(1, 11) + [10] * 3) * 4
base_names = ['A'] + range(2, 11) + ['J', 'K', 'Q']
cards = []
for suit in ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D']:
cards.extend(str(num) + suit for num in base_names)

deck = Series(card_val, index=cards)
```

Comment: What do you believe the result in `card_val` will be from the expression `(range(1, 11) + [10] * 3) * 4`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using Python 3 and `range()` is a generator in python 3. Encapsulate range inside a list. `list(range(10))`

card_val = (list(range(1, 11)) + [10] * 3) * 4

Comment: Appreciate the response and that worked for the 2 lines of code with ranges but now cards = [] is throwing up an invalid syntax error?  seems pretty straight forward and i've never had an empty list return an error especially for syntax

Comment: @MichaelPeterson What's the error? what is updated code?

Comment: # Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds
suits = ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D']
card_val = (list(range(1, 11)) + [10] * 3) * 4
base_names = (list(range(2, 11)) + ['A', 'J', 'K', 'Q']
cards = []
for suit in ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D']:
    cards.extend(str(num) + suit for num in base_names)

deck = Series(card_val, index=cards)

Comment: File "<ipython-input-121-38bf7a9401ad>", line 5
    cards = []
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MichaelPeterson You have an extra `(` here `base_names = (list(range(2, 11)) + ['A', 'J', 'K', 'Q']`. Make it `base_names = list(range(2, 11)) + ['A', 'J', 'K', 'Q']`

Comment: there must be an issue with this line of code                                   base_names = (list(range(2, 11)) + ['A', 'J', 'K', 'Q']